# Object Manipulation javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

i have a big problem to manipulate a js object. I have this object :

```
"daily_operator_trend": {
      "2018-08-01": {},
      "2018-08-02": {},
      "2018-07-16": {
        "1": 1,
        "2": 4,
        "3": 3
      },
      "2018-07-18": {
        "1": 1,
        "3": 7
      }
   }, 
  "operatorStats": [
    {
      "min_response_time": 5,
      "max_deepness": 3,
      "max_response_time": 5,
      "min_deepness": 3,
      "details": {
        "phoneNumber": "001122333",
        "allBots": true,
        "surname": "Sky",
        "nickname": "jesky",
        "name": "Je",
        "type": "owner",
        "operatorId": 1,
        "userId": "834f6de213c7d79bd64031371773b154",
        "email": "jesky@hotmail.it",
        "maxConversation": -1,
        "botIdList": [
          "1ec0e59069561da21727e3a56d05ef2d",
          "0ddfc38f54f51f7b40e1057436b34a6f",
          "37c43963d3e716bc4e41e1e6a32ed7f1"
        ]
      },
      "avg_deepness": 3,
      "avg_response_time": 5
    }]
```

Where in daily_operator_trend we have a key like a datae and a value is an object, in this object the key is the operator id and value is the num of conversation. I need to manipulate and transform it in a new array of object like this :

```
series: [ {name:'jesky', data:[0,0,1,1]}]
```

I'm trying with this code:

```
 let columnDataConv = data.operatorStats.reduce(function(map, obj){
    let newObj = [];
    let cData = Object.keys(data.daily_operator_trend).reduce(function(m, o){

      m['name'] = '';
      m['data'] = [];
      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data.daily_operator_trend[o])){
        if (key == obj.details.operatorId){
          if ( obj.details.nickname in m){
            m['data'].push(value);

          }else {
            m['name']= obj.details.nickname;
            m['data'].push(value);
          }

        }else {
          m['data'].push(0);
        }
        newObj.push(m);
      }
    return newObj;
    }, {})

    map={...cData};     

    return map;
  }, {});
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Where does the data part come from? What have you tried so far on your own?

Comment: what is `data: [0,0,1,1]` ?

Comment: data is the num coversation for each day. For example : { "2018-07-16":{"operatorId": num_conversations}} so i need to match the operator id with the operatorStats detail to take the nickname and then i need to create the "series" array of object

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = { 
"daily_operator_trend": {
          "2018-08-01": {
            "1": 1,
            "2": 4,
            "3": 3
          },
          "2018-08-02": {
            "1": 10,
            "2":15,
            "3":25
          },
          "2018-07-16": {
          },
},
  "operatorStats": [
        {
          "min_response_time": 5,
          "max_deepness": 3,
          "max_response_time": 5,
          "min_deepness": 3,
          "details": {
            "phoneNumber": "001122333",
            "allBots": true,
            "surname": "Sky",
            "nickname": "jesky",
            "name": "Je",
            "type": "owner",
            "operatorId": 1,
            "userId": "834f6de213c7d79bd64031371773b154",
            "email": "jesky@hotmail.it",
            "maxConversation": -1,
            "botIdList": [
              "1ec0e59069561da21727e3a56d05ef2d",
              "0ddfc38f54f51f7b40e1057436b34a6f",
              "37c43963d3e716bc4e41e1e6a32ed7f1"
            ]
          },
          "avg_deepness": 3,
          "avg_response_time": 5
        },
        {
          "min_response_time": 4,
          "max_deepness": 2,
          "max_response_time": 1,
          "min_deepness": 2,
          "details": {
            "phoneNumber": "001122333",
            "allBots": true,
            "surname": "SkyWine",
            "nickname": "john",
            "name": "Jeremy",
            "type": "owner",
            "operatorId": 2,
            "userId": "834f6de213c7d79bd64031371773b155",
            "email": "john@hotmail.it",
            "maxConversation": -1,
            "botIdList": [
              "1ec0e59069561da21727e3a56d05ef2d",
              "0ddfc38f54f51f7b40e1057436b34a6g",
              "37c43963d3e716bc4e41e1e6a32ed7f1"
            ]
          },
          "avg_deepness": 3,
          "avg_response_time": 5
        },
        {
          "min_response_time": 4,
          "max_deepness": 2,
          "max_response_time": 1,
          "min_deepness": 5,
          "details": {
            "phoneNumber": "001122333",
            "allBots": true,
            "surname": "SkyWine",
            "nickname": "Frank",
            "name": "Jeremy",
            "type": "owner",
            "operatorId": 3,
            "userId": "834f6de213c7d79bd64031371773b156",
            "email": "frank@hotmail.it",
            "maxConversation": -1,
            "botIdList": [
              "1ec0e59069561da21727e3a56d05ef2d",
              "0ddfc38f54f51f7b40e1057436b34a6f",
              "37c43963d3e716bc4e41e1e6a32ed7f2"
            ]
          },
          "avg_deepness": 3,
          "avg_esponse_time": 5
        }
      ]
};
function mergeNames (arr) {
    return _.chain(arr).groupBy('name').mapValues(function (v) {
        return _.chain(v).pluck('value').flattenDeep();
    }).value();
}



let newObj = [];
      let columnDataConv = data.operatorStats.reduce(function(map, obj){

        for (let [k,v] of Object.entries(data.daily_operator_trend)){

          for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(v)){
            let m = {};
            let dati = [];
            if (key == obj.details.operatorId){
             if(newObj.length > 0){
              for(let i = 0;i< newObj.length; ++i){
                if(newObj[i].name === obj.details.nickname){
                  dati=[];
                  dati.push(value);
                  newObj[i].data.push(...dati);
                  break;
                }else{
                  dati=[];
                  m = {};
                  m['name']= obj.details.nickname;
                  dati.push(value);
                  m['data']=dati;   
                  newObj.push(m); 
                    break;
                }             
               };
              }else{
                  dati=[];
                  m = {};
                  m['name']= obj.details.nickname;
                  dati.push(value);
                  m['data']=dati;   
                  newObj.push(m); 
                break;

              }           
            }        
          }           
        }

        map={...newObj};     

        return map;
      }, []);
console.log(columnDataConv);
```

Now i have the array of objects but only the first entry of my array is correct. Why the other element aren't merged?